# Hybris webservices always sets anonymous user as current user

Tags: java, oauth, swagger, sap-commerce-cloud

I've added to my storefront a new extension based on commercewebservices and I've tested several sample services directly through swagger and the ones that doesn't need any kind of authorization works perfect. However, the webservices annotated with `@ApiBaseSiteIdAndUserIdParam` when I set the userId and siteParam the controller that interecepts this petition doesn't set in session the user I pass, it always returns anonymous user. I've tried creating special OAuth credentials but it doesn't work it always returns anonymous user.

```
   @Secured({ "ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT", "ROLE_CUSTOMERMANAGERGROUP" })
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
@ResponseBody
@ApiBaseSiteIdAndUserIdParam
public TestListWsDTO getTest(
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = DEFAULT_FIELD_SET) final String fields) {
    final CustomerData customerData = customerFacade.getCurrentCustomer();
    if (userFacade.isAnonymousUser()) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("Anonymous user is not allowed");
    }
```

[image]

[image]

The test@test.com is a registered user.

Why the customer I indicate through swagger is not being captured by customerFacade.getCurrentCustomer() and it always return anonymous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS per @Neil it's correct in case of OCC V2 context user is getting determined by the OAuth token.

For OCC there are also configured filters which used to configure or put user users in session if it got found otherwise it will set anonymous.

Please have a look of UserMatchingFilter.

```
/*
 * [y] hybris Platform
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2017 SAP SE or an SAP affiliate company.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * This software is the confidential and proprietary information of SAP
 * ("Confidential Information"). You shall not disclose such Confidential
 * Information and shall use it only in accordance with the terms of the
 * license agreement you entered into with SAP.
 */
package de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.v2.filter;

import de.hybris.platform.core.model.user.UserModel;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.UnknownIdentifierException;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionService;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.user.UserService;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;


/**
 * Filter that puts user from the requested url into the session.
 */
public class UserMatchingFilter extends AbstractUrlMatchingFilter
{
    public static final String ROLE_ANONYMOUS = "ROLE_ANONYMOUS";
    public static final String ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP = "ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP";
    public static final String ROLE_CUSTOMERMANAGERGROUP = "ROLE_CUSTOMERMANAGERGROUP";
    public static final String ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT = "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT";
    private static final String CURRENT_USER = "current";
    private static final String ANONYMOUS_USER = "anonymous";
    private static final String ACTING_USER_UID = "ACTING_USER_UID";
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UserMatchingFilter.class);
    private String regexp;
    private UserService userService;
    private SessionService sessionService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        final Authentication auth = getAuth();
        if (hasRole(ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP, auth) || hasRole(ROLE_CUSTOMERMANAGERGROUP, auth))
        {
            getSessionService().setAttribute(ACTING_USER_UID, auth.getPrincipal());
        }

        final String userID = getValue(request, regexp);
        if (userID == null)
        {
            if (hasRole(ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP, auth) || hasRole(ROLE_CUSTOMERMANAGERGROUP, auth))
            {
                setCurrentUser((String) auth.getPrincipal());
            }
            else
            {
                // fallback to anonymous
                setCurrentUser(userService.getAnonymousUser());
            }
        }
        else if (userID.equals(ANONYMOUS_USER))
        {
            setCurrentUser(userService.getAnonymousUser());
        }
        else if (hasRole(ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT, auth) || hasRole(ROLE_CUSTOMERMANAGERGROUP, auth))
        {
            setCurrentUser(userID);
        }
        else if (hasRole(ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP, auth))
        {
            if (userID.equals(CURRENT_USER) || userID.equals(auth.getPrincipal()))
            {
                setCurrentUser((String) auth.getPrincipal());
            }
            else
            {
                throw new AccessDeniedException("Access is denied");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // could not match any authorized role
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Access is denied");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    protected Authentication getAuth()
    {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }

    protected String getRegexp()
    {
        return regexp;
    }

    @Required
    public void setRegexp(final String regexp)
    {
        this.regexp = regexp;
    }

    protected UserService getUserService()
    {
        return userService;
    }

    @Required
    public void setUserService(final UserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    protected SessionService getSessionService()
    {
        return sessionService;
    }

    @Required
    public void setSessionService(final SessionService sessionService)
    {
        this.sessionService = sessionService;
    }

    protected boolean hasRole(final String role, final Authentication auth)
    {
        if (auth != null)
        {
            for (final GrantedAuthority ga : auth.getAuthorities())
            {
                if (ga.getAuthority().equals(role))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void setCurrentUser(final String uid)
    {
        try
        {
            final UserModel userModel = userService.getUserForUID(uid);
            userService.setCurrentUser(userModel);
        }
        catch (final UnknownIdentifierException ex)
        {
            LOG.debug(ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected void setCurrentUser(final UserModel user)
    {
        userService.setCurrentUser(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was missing the UserMatchingFilter in my filter chain list, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In an OCC context, the current user is determined by the OAuth token.  If you just have the client credentials then you are Anonymous.  However after a user-specific login you have a different token that correlates to the user that authenticated with OAuth.  There should be a filter in the commercewebservices stack that checks the token & maps to a current user in the temporary session. As far as I'm aware only that user will appear as the current customer, not the one passed in the URL ... you probably want to check that the current customer is the same user (or should have permission to see details about that user)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OCC web services, these services are stateless. So you cannot get any values from session variables. Generally facades using by storefront and storefronts are using sessions.

Comment: Well yes & no.  Some internal services rely on a session, so there are filters that construct a basic session for the length of the call.  Code running after the fiulters can get those values from the temporary session